Firestore Security Rules: Insufficient Permissions Error When Querying Items Collection
I'm working on a Firestore project with the following data structure:

lists collection

{
  id: '12345',
  title: 'Example List',
  owner: ['user1', 'user2']
}



items collection

{
  id: '67890',
  title: 'Example Item',
  listId: '12345',
  toSchedule: true
}

Each item belongs to a list and is linked to it by the listId field. Lists are owned by users whose IDs are included in the owner array. I want to set up Firestore security rules to ensure that only the owners of a list can read/write/delete the items associated with that list.
Firestore Security Rules
Here's the security rule setup I have:
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /lists/{listId} {
      // Allow creation if the owner array contains the user's UID
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.owner.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);
      
      // Allow read, write, delete if the user is an owner
      allow get, list, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.owner;
    }
   
    
    match /items/{itemId} {
      function isOwnerOfList(listId) {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/lists/$(listId)).data.owner.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);
      }
      
      // Allow creation if the owner array contains the user's UID
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.owner.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);
      
      // Allow read, write, delete if the user is an owner of the associated list
      allow get, list, update, delete: if isOwnerOfList(resource.data.listId);
    }
  }
}

Frontend code
Here's the frontend code I'm using to query the items collection:
 const Query = async (collectionName, additionalConditions = []) => {
    const conditions = [...additionalConditions];
    return onSnapshot( 
      query(collection(db, collectionName), 
      ...conditions
    ), 
      snapshot => Snapshot(snapshot, collectionName, dispatch),
      error => console.log('snapshot listener error', error)
    )
  }
 

  Query('lists', [where('owner', 'array-contains', user)]) // This works
  Query('items', [where('listId', '==', '_uNygDJjiwhdEoUPnZO_')]) // This works
  Query('items', [where('toSchedule', '==', true)]) // This throws the insufficient permissions error

Issue
When executing Query('items', [where('toSchedule', '==', true)]), I receive the following error: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. 
Additional Information

The user is authenticated and their UID is correctly being retrieved.
I don't want to keep an owner field on the items collections, because lists can be shared with different people, allowing them to have multiple owners.
The owner array in the lists document does contain the authenticated user's UID.
I suspect the issue might be related to how the security rules are set up for the items collection, particularly with the isOwnerOfList function.

Question
What changes do I need to make to my Firestore security rules or frontend code to allow querying the items collection with additional conditions like where('toSchedule', '==', true) without encountering permission errors?
Thank you for your help!

Query('items', [where('toSchedule', '==', true)]) does not work with your security rules because rules are not filters:

You cannot write a query (returning some) documents in a collection and expect Cloud Firestore to return only the documents that the current client has permission to access.

You need to combine this query with the [where('owner', 'array-contains', user)] one.

Query('items', [where('owner', 'array-contains', user), where('toSchedule', '==', true)]) still results in FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. I understand why the error is thrown now, thanks to the answer, but don't know how to fix it. Some items are part of a specific list but may appear also on a "consolidated" list depending on a certain field value, like toSchedule === true. Not sure how to data model that properly together with secure rules.
